# Store payment success data on database

Tags: laravel, database, stripe-payments, payment-gateway, store

i have done payment gateway using stripe , payment is getting succeed in stripe , how can i set success in my checkout table with all details of user , i do not have any column for payment in checkout also i don't know how exactly stripe works ,

let me know if anyone can help me in this

This is my stripe code

```
$userId = Auth::id();
        // code of online payment starts
        // Enter Your Stripe Secret
        \Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey('sk_test_51NUj9NSCBDBzYpgwK1lDUIy49i02R3KB8tWaU78XYXluNB4LaBwToHdcPp2kqZraydfqRxvtaMJ1Gm3pgOYO5KaN00FiJHCWJU');
        $result = Order_user::where('userid', $userId)
            ->select(DB::raw('SUM(price) as total_price'))
            ->first();
        $totalPrice = $result->total_price;
        $shipping_charge = Shipping_charge::select('s_charge')->where('id', 1)->first()->s_charge;
        $shipping_charge = intval($shipping_charge);

        // Calculate the payment amount including the shipping charge
        $amount = ($totalPrice + $shipping_charge) * 100;
        $payment_intent = \Stripe\PaymentIntent::create([
            'description' => 'Stripe Test Payment',
            'amount' => $amount,
            'currency' => 'INR',
            'payment_method_types' => ['card'],
        ]);
        $intent = $payment_intent->client_secret;

        // code of online payment ends

        $order_data = Order_user::join('product', 'order_user.pid', '=', 'product.id')
            ->where('order_user.userid', $userId)
            ->select('order_user.*', 'product.product_name')
            ->get();
        $shipping_charge = Shipping_charge::where('id', 1)->value('s_charge');
        return view("checkout", ['order_data' => $order_data, 'shipping_charge' => $shipping_charge, 'intent' => $intent]);
```

and this is my post code along with payment these data are coming

```
$shipping_charge = Shipping_charge::select('s_charge')->where('id', 1)->first()->s_charge;
        $userId = Auth::id();
        $first_name = $request->input('firstName');
        $last_name = $request->input('lastName');
        $email = $request->input('email');
        $mobile_no = $request->input('mobileno');
        $b_address = $request->input('baddress');
        $s_address = $request->input('saddress');
        $checkout = Checkout::insertGetId([
            'userid' => $userId,
            'first_name' => $first_name,
            'last_name' => $last_name,
            'email' => $email,
            'mobile_no' => $mobile_no,
            'b_address' => $b_address,
            's_address' => $s_address,
            's_charge' => $shipping_charge,
            'created_at' => now(),
            'updated_at' => now()
        ]);
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely sure how you're integrating with Stripe. Normally, Stripe recommends using [webhooks](https://stripe.com/docs/webhooks) to listen to events such as `payment_intent.succeeded` which returns the PaymentIntent [object](https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_intents/object) holding the Payment's information. I hope this is enough to unblock you.